# How to programmatically get option id's and values from configurable product in phtml?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am modifying phtml code were I have access to

$this which happens to be Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Configurable class

and

```
$_item = $this->getItem();
$_product = $_item->getProduct();
```

where product is a configurable product in a cart.

Based on this I need to get a list of option id (swatches) and their values.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to get specific size option id :

```
$product = $_item->getProduct();
$idStore = $_item->getOrder()->getStoreId();
$sizeSpecificAttributeCode = 'specific_size';
$sizeAttributeOptionId = $product->getResource()
->getAttributeRawValue($product->getId(), $sizeSpecificAttributeCode,$idStore);
```

from the same logic you can get the swatches or other options